# Python - How to create multiple databases with SQLALCHEMY in Flask?

Tags: python, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm making a web app with Flask using SQLALCHEMY to management the databases.

I need to store in more then one database. For example: "user_databse.sb" and "teacher_database.db".

I read the documentation to do this, but when I try to use in my code I getting this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

Thats my code:

```
   path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
   
   app = Flask(__name__)

   app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secretkey'
   app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(path, 'databaseteste.db')
   app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
   app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {
      'user_database': 'mysql:///root:password@localhost/userdatabase'
   }
   
   
   db = SQLAlchemy(app)
   
   # User model to database
   class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
       __bind_key__ = 'user_database'
       id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
       username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
       email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique = True, index = True)
       password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
       joined_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default = datetime.utcnow, index = True)
   
       def __repr__(self):
           return f'User {self.username}'
       
       def set_passoword(self, password):
           self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)
   ...
```

Can someone help me to find what I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem in the code.

I just change the root in `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS']`

```
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
   
   app = Flask(__name__)

   app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secretkey'
   app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(path, 'databaseteste.db')
   app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
   app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {
      'user_database': 'mysql:///root:password@localhost/userdatabase'
   }
```

Just changed to my path and change the `mysql` to `sqlite`:

`'user_database': 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(path, 'database/user_database.db')`